# JavaFX, FXML, login form and change stages or scenes

Tags: java, javafx, authentication, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I made simple login form with Scene Builder.
Login form work fine, but when I enter user/pass and Main window open, Login window is still opened. How to close it? Regards.

Here is code DomaciFinal.java:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

MainController.java:

```
public class MainController {

@FXML
private Label lblStatus;

@FXML
private TextField txtUserName;

@FXML
private TextField txtPassword;

public void Login(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    if (txtUserName.getText().equals("user") && txtPassword.getText().equals("pass")) {
        lblStatus.setText("Uspešno ste ulogovani.");
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } else {
        lblStatus.setText("Neispravni podaci.");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `txtUserName.getScene().getWindow().hide();`

Comment: @James_D Thank you verry much, it works! :)
Can you explain me this line of code? Regards!

Comment: There’s not much to explain. `txtUserName.getScene()` returns the scene which contains the text field `txtUserName`. `getWindow()` returns the window containing the scene. `hide()` hides (closes) the window.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take would be simply to set the scene of the original stage to your main scene.
 You would need to alter your main class to store the stage and add a getter to get the primaryStage and then use it instead of primaryStage withing the Login method.

Comment: You don't really need to do this assuming the login scene is displayed in this window, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391416/javafx-fxml-login-form-and-change-stages-or-scenes#comment87798881_50391416